# I want to use onclick function to get data from HTML Form inside php loop to use it in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developing discussion board and I want to make a reply system on each comment using jquery.
I created certain div inside a loop with different values in each iteration.

Now I'm working on submitting the reply form and I have a problem. It works only on the first comment. When I reply to the first comment only It works but when replying to any other comment It doesn't work and give me my error message the textbox is empty Then I realized that it reads data from the first form only through the loop.

Here is the code.

```
<div class="comment_form">
  <textarea class="span10" id="replyC" name="replyC" placeholder="Reply comment" rows="6">
</textarea><br>
 <input id="commentId" name="commentId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $CommentID;?>"> 
<input id="userId" name="userId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $uId;?>"> 
<input id="articleId" name="articleId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ArticleID; ?>"> 
<input class="btn btn-lg btn-default replyForm" id="<?php echo $CommentID; ?>" name="replyForm" type="submit" value="Reply">
    </div>
```

The button with class name "replyForm" I get it by

```
$(".replyForm").click(function()
  and here is the javascript and Ajax code.

  $(".replyForm").click(function(){
  //$(this).parents().next('.replyForm').click(function(){ 
  var user_reply = $("#replyC").val();
  var userId = $("#userId").val();
  var comment_id = $("#commentId").val();
  var articleId = $("#articleId").val();


  $.ajax({
  url:'articleReply.php',
  data:{replyC:user_reply,userId:userId,commentId:comment_id,articleId:articleId},
  type:'POST',
  success:function(data){
  $("#resultReply").html(data);
  $('#replyC').val('');
  }
  });
  });
```

The problem Now .. It doesn't work on all comments retrieved from the loop but works only on the first comment while trying reply on other comments I get my empty message appears under the first comment.
So it get data from the first comment only not from the rest.
Any help ??

Here it works:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6tNJ.png]

Here is the problem:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuRXl.png]

Comment: Don't you have repeating IDs in your code?

Comment: id are unique identificator

Comment: What loop?  Where is the code that shows the message you're seeing?  This looks very incomplete.  Though if that first HTML code sample is what's in your loop then you have invalid HTML because you're re-using `id` values.  So when you do this: `$("#replyC")`, how would the code know *which* element you meant?

Comment: Can we see articleReply.php ?

Comment: Try to include your form tag inside loop. It will work

Comment: I'm not using form to avoid reloading the page.
So I work with just buttons and Ajax.

Comment: dont use id's for get the values, instead use like $(this).siblings().find("input[name='userId']")

Comment: My bad. So your .replyForm when clicked need to set .commentForm > hidden inputs wtih current comment datas. Problem is there.

Comment: so can u guide me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: David - The form above is hidden inside a php loop and I want get different data from it every time I choose a certain comment to reply.
the problem is I get data from the first form shown in the first comment. When I try to show another form and write in it also takes values from the first form only which empty.